# Logging an event for CD creation?

Tags: rhel, logs, data-cd, burning

How can I tell from Linux logs (Red Hat in particular) that a user burned a CD?

Does Linux log an event or events when a CD is burned from the built-in burning solution (or other burning software)? 
Can it be set to log an event that would indicate a CD burning event happened? 
Is there a way to deduce this event occurred?

Comment: There might be complex programmatic ways to determine this, but it would be difficult to differentiate burning an optical disk from any other use of `mkfs` or `dd` or `cat` or any other means of writing to a block device.  You _could_ monitor open file handles for the CD block device, but even that would not be realtime and would not be guaranteed to only detect the burning of an image rather than just writing to an extant filesystem on a rewritable optical medium.

Comment: I think there'll be traces in the kernel logs. At the very least there should be an indication that a blank disk was inserted.